# Select one item from Series and keep the index

Tags: python, pandas

If I select a single item from a `pd.Series` using either `.loc` or just straightforward indexing, a single value is returned.

Pandas automatically 'squeezes' the result:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C'], index=[10, 20, 30])
>>> s[10]
'A'
>>> s.loc[10]
'A'
```

Although this is almost always what we want, sometimes I'd like to know "where" a single value came from in a bigger series.

How can I prevent this default squeezing? In other words, I'd like to create a 1-element series like this:

```
10   A
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Use double `[]` for select by one element list:

```
print (s.loc[[10]])
10    A
dtype: object
```